# Flutter doesn't load project properly

Tags: android, flutter, sdk

I have been trying to fix this problem for 3 days, I'm really interested in switching to flutter, I downloaded the sdk and did everything in the flutter docs
this is what happens when a start a new flutter project in android studio
[Look here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXUyd.png)

I tried in vs code also and got this error

[See this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3Zt8.png)

[Look here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IR1gc.png)

Solutions I have tried: redownload the sdk, check if windows is blocking files, browse and choose the dart sdk in the android studio, Flutter doctor results say everything is okay

Answer (score 0):

Try writing `flutter create MyApp` in VSCode..
As flutter doctor is telling everything is fine with your sdk, this should not create this issue.

Try adding `'your_path'/flutter/bin` in environment variable(Control Panel > User Accounts > User Accounts > Change my environment variables)..

Comment: still give me the 
'where' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: Try running 'where flutter' : this should give the path to flutter sdk..........